# How can I back out an Android update without rooting the device?

Tags: media-player, android-4.4-kitkat

I have been working on a project I needed handing do in in the next few days.

It uses MediaPlayer, just to play back a 3gp voice file, nothing too complicated.

I have a moto g phone, I updated to Android version 4.4.4 and since then the mediaplayer will not work correctly.

I so wish I had ignored the update.

My project involves sending voice data to other phones and playing back the other phones are Nexus 4 with Android 4.4 and these seem ok.
I can't root the phones.
Maybe I need an alternative to MediaPlayer just to play back the voice file.
Any help/advise would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Panic over, it was a bug elsewhere in the code, just a horrible coincidence that it reared its head just after a update.